# Why does my Apple Watch glow green sometimes?

Tags: apple-watch

Every now and then, I’ll notice the back of my Apple Watch glowing with a green LED light. It seems to happen sporadically and usually only lasts for a few seconds.

Why does my Apple Watch glow green sometimes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's taking your heart rate.

Per [Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204666):

> "Blood is red because it reflects red light and absorbs green light. Apple Watch uses **green LED lights** paired with light‑sensitive photodiodes to detect the amount of blood flowing through your wrist at any given moment. When your heart beats, the blood flow in your wrist - and the green light absorption - is greater. Between beats, it's less. By flashing its LED lights hundreds of times per second, Apple Watch can calculate the number of times the heart beats each minute - your heart rate."
>
> [image: Back of Apple Watch]

The green LED's actually are flashing hundreds of times each second so to you it looks like it's glowing, but it's not.